# Jenkins throws error instantiating firefox, works fine with Maven

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, mozilla, geckodriver

```
1515175026602   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" "-marionette" "-profile" "C:\\Windows\\TEMP\\rust_mozprofile.MX9tmRHWAJFL"
1515175027227   Marionette  INFO    Enabled via --marionette
###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x240057,name=PContent::Msg_SetPluginList) Channel error: cannot send/recv


###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24004C,name=PContent::Msg_GMPsChanged) Channel error: cannot send/recv


###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x15008F,name=PBrowser::Msg_UpdateNativeWindowHandle) Channel error: cannot send/recv


###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x150083,name=PBrowser::Msg_Destroy) Channel error: cannot send/recv

A content process crashed and MOZ_CRASHREPORTER_SHUTDOWN is set, shutting down
```

Comment: I am seeing similar with VSTS private agent on Win Server 2016.

Answer (score 1):

The issue got fixed by installing Jenkins using jenkins.war in the command prompt. Earlier I have installed using .exe file as like usual windows softwares.

.exe instals it as a windows service and .war as a java executable

Run "java -jar jenkins.war" on cmd, configure and run the build, would resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

this issue may be with unsupported security preferences set up in code, I faced this issue in mac while I was setting up this preference in FF v62. and gecko 0.24

```
                        profile.setPreference("security.sandbox.content.level", 5);
```